# Adding a master detail to a navigation drawer layout

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a navigation drawer with two items; Locations and Maps. When the user clicks on Locations a listview of locations should show. When the user clicks on Map; a map will show. I am able to show the map, but the listview is not visible. I have tried all different ways such as a fragment or as an activity, extending ListFragment and ListActivity with no luck. I am able to display a textView using either method mentioned. As soon as I try to implement the listview nothing works and there are no errors or crashes, just a blank screen. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Navigation drawer method that changes the views:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        View rootView = null;
        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)) {
            case 1:
                //rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_location, container, false);
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return rootView;
```

Fragment that displays the listview:

```
public class LocationsFragment extends ListFragment {


public LocationsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);
    String[] values = new String[] {"Location 1", "Location 2", "Location 3"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_locations, container, false);
}
```

}

I hope this helps. Let me know if you want to see more. Please note that this code is only to display a listview. My ultimate goal is to be able to display details about a location when one is clicked.

Comment: Posting code can help

Comment: That's a lot of code, what do you want to see??

Comment: I hope you are implementing Navigation Drawer properly! Just make a demo app with list fragment and if it works copy that code to your project.

Comment: ok, I'll try that. I'm pretty sure I am implementing the nav drawer correctly because I am using the template provided by Android Studio.